# Server failed to start: No such property: localHttpPort for class: org.grails.jetty.JettyServer

Tags: grails, groovy, jetty, grails-plugin

I'm trying to take a project from Grails 2.1.5 to Grails 2.2.5.  I had to make a few minor tweaks to get everything to compile, but now I'm getting this error when trying to start my application:

Server failed to start: No such property: localHttpPort for class: org.grails.jetty.JettyServer

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to do.  I tried specifying localHttpPort in my BuildConfig.xml as well as a few less-sensible places.

Any advice?

Comment: Haven't you add an extra `localHttpPort` property, which is not recognised by the framework? Please `grep -rn localHttpPort` and check out where are you using it (and clean it).

Comment: I can't find any reference to localHttpPort anywhere.